# Regex Number reservations

Tags: php, html, regex

Good afternoon, I am creating a form with a number reservation field, for the user to pick. The system i had would only allow the reservation number by number, example: `1,2,3` and it would book the numbers 1,2 and 3.

Now i would like to add the option to book several numbers at once, example: `1-5,9,10`and in this case it would book numbers 1 to 5, 9 and 10.

I'm using the following regex code, but it's not working as I want

```
^\d{1,5}(?:-\d{1,5})*(?:,\d{1,5})*(?:,\d{1,5}-\d{1,5})*(?:-\d{1,5},\d{1,5})*$
```

The problem with this code is whenever the user inserts two `1-3,4-6` it only allows one more number. For example `1-3,4-6,2,3` shows error when the `,3` is inserted.

There is also a problem where it allows to write several dashes without commas
example `1-3-6-8-9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps something like this:

```
\A\d{1,5}(?:-\d{1,5})?(?:,\d{1,5}(?:-\d{1,5})?)*\z
```

The idea:

- the range is optional `(?:-\d{1,5})?` (and follows the first number)
- The group, that contains a comma followed by a number or a range, can occur zero or more times

Note that a problem can't be solved by regex since `6-4` or `1-5,2,3,4` are always possible. So you will need sooner or later to explode the string and to check if numbers and ranges are coherent.

Comment: This is exactly what I was forgetting, insert a group inside the other! Yes I understand this is simply for string format, I'm now working on a function to check any kind of errors with the string with php. Thank you for the fast response

Comment: There is just one thing i don't uderstan, why did you insert the `\A` and `\z` in the code?

Comment: @SandroG `\A` and `\z` are anchors for start and end of string. There are  little differences with `^` and `$`: The maining of `\A` and `\z` doesn't change in multiline mode (so using them is more explicit). `$` is for the end of string, but it can match too the end of the line when followed by a single newline at the end of the string (this behaviour can be disabled with the `D` modifier.)

Comment: So using the `^` and `$`wouldn't be a problem if it wasn't a multiline case?